# communcation between pc and android for sending string using php

Tags: php

i want to transfer string from pc to android phone . Is there any technique to transfer string from pc to phone using the php or any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a web service in order to do this, added better example.[Link](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123)

Answer (score 0):

you can use json approach visit the following link it will help.

[Connection between PHP (server) and Android (client) Using HTTP and JSON](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)

Comment: i want to send string from pc to phone , not from phone to pc